# Solution display loading for waiting Webview load page in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have to load [trading view](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/). I use [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) to do that. It lost a few seconds to load. I want to show the loading view until Webview finishes load page. My idea is use a stack and loading view stands over webview. But I don't know how to remove loading view when webview done. Any solution for this ?

```
 Widget loadTradingView() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      height: Get.width,
      child: Stack(children: [
        loadingView(),
        WebView(
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (webController) {
            _loadHtmlFromAssets(webController);
          },
          onPageFinished: (str) {
           
            print('done');
          },
          onPageStarted: (str) {
            print('start');
          },
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use webview inside stateful widget and call `setState` to show/hide loader. Example code:

```dart
class WebViewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  WebViewWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WebViewWidgetState createState() => _WebViewWidgetState();
}

class _WebViewWidgetState extends State<WebViewWidget> {
  var _loading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      height: Get.width,
      child: Stack(children: [
        if (_loading) loadingView(),  // Show/hide loader depends on [_loading] flag
        WebView(
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (webController) {
            _loadHtmlFromAssets(webController);
          },
          onPageFinished: (str) {
            print('done');
            setState(() {
              _loading = false;
            });
          },
          onPageStarted: (str) {
            print('start');
            setState(() {
              _loading = true;
            });
          },
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```